# Boost up File encryption

Tags: android, cryptography

this is a small part of my Droidscript plugin...

it Receives the command from Droidscript and encrypts or decrypts the file as per the command...

It is working fine but is a bit slower.

```
private void Decrypt( Bundle b )
    {
        try {
            String srcFil = b.getString("p1");
            String dstFil = b.getString("p2");
            String key = b.getString("p3"); // atl least 8 characters

            // needs to be at least 8 characters for DES
// Decrypt file :-
             BufferedInputStream fis2 = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(srcFil));     // encrypted file to decrypt
             BufferedOutputStream fos2 = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(dstFil));     // original after decrypt
             decrypt(key, fis2, fos2);


        } catch (Throwable d) {
            d.printStackTrace();

        } 
    }
private void Encrypt( Bundle b) {
    try {
        String srcFil = b.getString("p1");
        String dstFil = b.getString("p2");
        String key = b.getString("p3"); // atl least 8 characters

         // needs to be at least 8 characters for DES
// encrypt file :-
        BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(srcFil));// Orig file to encrypt


        BufferedOutputStream fos =new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(dstFil));// encrypted file name
        encrypt(key, fis, fos);

    } catch (Throwable d) {
        d.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public static void encrypt(String key, BufferedInputStream is, BufferedOutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void decrypt(String key, BufferedInputStream is, BufferedOutputStream os) throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void encryptOrDecrypt(String key, int mode, BufferedInputStream is, BufferedOutputStream os) throws Throwable {

    DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); // DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for SunJCE

    if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        /**CipherInputStream*/BufferedInputStream cis = new BufferedInputStream( new CipherInputStream(is, cipher));
        doCopy(cis, os);

    } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        BufferedOutputStream cos = new BufferedOutputStream(  new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher));
        doCopy(is, cos);
    }
}

public static void doCopy(BufferedInputStream is, BufferedOutputStream os) throws IOException {

     byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
     int numBytes;
     while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
     os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
     }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
}
```

so, I want you to help me to increase its encryption and decryption speed up to at least 10mb/s.

besides, it is just a plugin so it does not include any xml file including AndroidManifest.xml and also do not include any assets and res,
so how can I make it able to write data to external sdcard.
when the file destination is specified to extSDCard it does not write encrypted to the extSDCard.

Comment: How do you know that encryption is slowing you down? You need to benchmark with and without encryption to see what effect encryption has on your performance. AES is comparable in speed to DES and may be faster depending on hardware support. AES is a strong algorithm whereas DES is always weak has been obsolete for more than 20 years.

Comment: Its encryption speed is somewhat 4mb/s and I want it to be at least 8mb/s

Comment: isn't it possible to send the data in byte array i.e. 8mb at a time to the encrypt stream...?

Comment: thanks, I just realized that I am using a weak encryption method DES , thoroughly I will convert it to AES encryption method... but I have a great problem, As I told you that it is a plugin and will not contain any permission file( AndroidManifest.xml) so, I have a problem in writing the encrypted/decrypted file to the external storage. would you please make this program able to write the output file to the device external storage(extSDCard)! currently it writes file only to the internal storage.